# Post request from html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have `<script>var foo=bar;</script>` .I want to write a fucntion in the same script tag which sends data (bar) to http://example.com/get-data/.
I don't know much knowledge about js.

```
<body>
    <script>
    var hash_token = window.location.hash;
    removed_hash_token=hash_token.slice(1);
    alert(removed_hash_token)
    get_token_url="http://localhost:8000/"
    </script>
</body>
```

see I have hash fragment after login  google redirecting  in url,so I take hash and remove it and I want to send this to backend .

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @David edited question,And I want to make it simple explanation.

Comment: *"and I want to send this to backend"* - The technology you're *probably* looking for is called AJAX.  You can use that terminology to find tutorials and examples on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

Answer (score 0):

using what @SwaD suggested I came up with answer,thank you to guide me.

answer:

```
<script>
    var hash_token = window.location.hash;
    removed_hash_token = hash_token.slice(1);
    alert(removed_hash_token);
    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/calender/", { "token_hash": removed_hash_token })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
</script>
```